# Fancybox Error on Youtube IFrame Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, fancybox

I added on my page a FrancyBox Youtube Iframe, but when i close the Iframe i get dialogs from Interet explorer 9.0 (about 15 or above) with Javascript Errors.

http://descuentalomallorca.com/uploads/fancy/demo/index.html

This just happens on the Youtube link, i tried also in the examples of:
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

and im getting the same result, any ideas?

Img of the error http://descuentalomallorca.com/uploads/fancy/fancy.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't your code. If you try the Youtube link on the fancybox website, you'll see that it also happens there. Even on Fancybox 2.

You can either find the source of the problem in the uncompressed version, or switch to using another library. One such library is [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox). The youtube example they have there doesn't have those callback errors. qTip2 also works, but not really designed for the fancybox like implementation. There are likely many more libraries and googling fancybox alternatives will find them.

Comment: I saw that this happens also on fancybox page, but anyway i tried Colorbox as you said: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/ and surprisely i get the same error closing the youtube iFrame, test it

Comment: JFK is right. It's an IE9 thing that I must have missed. `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` is a workaround. Should accept his answer.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me (very bad code trick I know)

Adding a `beforeClose` event on the fancybox. The function will first set the src of the iframe to `about:blank`, and after 500 ms it will really close the fancybox (directly closing it will still get the error)

```
beforeClose : function() { 
  if(!window.mayclosebox) {
    $('.fancybox-iframe').attr('src','about:blank');window.mayclosebox = true;setTimeout('$.fancybox.close();',500);return false;
  } else { 
    window.mayclosebox = false;return true; 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The bug has been reported with other lightboxes too, including colorbox (ditching fancybox as previously proposed is not the solution)... it's more like a IE9 bug. You can [read more here](http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/d897086b0e3775ca?pli=1)

Somebody that reported the same issue with [colorbox](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/colorbox/Ni93eC5JZ8E) seemed to have found a workaround adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Comment: I must have missed IE9 when I was swapping out the Browser modes for Colorbox. Thought I tested all the modes.